# RegionIntersection of Regions

Tags: graphics, regions

This code does what I expected: It displays the region of intersection between
two disks:

```
Region[
 RegionIntersection[
  Disk[{0, 0}, 1],
  Disk[{3/2, 1/4}, 3/4]
  ]
 ]
```

---

[image: Lune]

---

I expected this to do the same, but it does not:

```
R1 = Region[Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
R2 = Region[Disk[{3/2, 1/4}, 3/4]];
Region[
 RegionIntersection[R1, R2]
 ]
```

It runs for a long time, and I've not had the patience to see if it ever
displays the lune intersection.

Can anyone explain the difference?

**Update**. @HenrikSchumacher's comments showed that the problem is that there
was a `Region` bug in version 11.1.1, which I was using, a bug fixed by version 11.3.

Comment: No explanation here. It executes quickly and returns the same result exactly as the first example in my copy of version 11.3 for macOS. But Mathematica cuts off the two tips. I guess, `Region` is meant to represent exact regions while the visual return of a `Region` is a coarse discritization solely meant for a quick preview.

Comment: You can always convert to a `MeshRegion` or a `BoundaryMeshRegion` with customized resolution by `DiscretizeRegion` and `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`. For example, the latter two have the option `MaxCellMeasure` that allows you to adjust how fine the discretization should be done. In total, all `Region`-related functionalities are rather new and a bit buggy; this is true in particular for `BooleanRegion` which is used under the hood (as you can see by inspecting `FullForm[RegionIntersection[R1, R2]]`).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Perhaps the difference is that I am using 11.1.1.0 MacOS. Time to update!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: That was it---Works just as you describe in 11.3.0.0. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that! You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
R1 = Region[Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
R2 = Region[Disk[{3/2, 1/4}, 3/4]];
RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[R1, R2]]
```

works fine.